# SyntaxError : Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm coding a Discord bot in `discord.js`. I've gotten a bit through my code and had no problems finding ways to fix things, but recently I tried to add a help command. And every time I run the cmd I get [this](http://prntscr.com/ii94qd).

My code is

```
//tips
// '\n' = new line


//Requited
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const YTDL = require("ytdl-core");
const fs = require('fs');
const prefix = "!";
const TOKEN = ("This is where my token is");
const commands = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('commands.json', 'utf8'));


var bot = new Discord.Client();
var servers = {};


//Boot Up
bot.on("ready", function() {
  console.log("Logged in and Ready!");
bot.user.setStatus('Online');
bot.user.setActivity('Roblox4Lyfe <3');
});


//Commands
bot.on('message', message => {
    let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
    let sender = message.author;
    let cont = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
    let args = cont.slice(1);

    //Help System
    if (meg.startsWith(prefix + 'HELP')) {
        if (msg === '${prefix}HELP') {
            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor(0x1D82B6)
        let commands = 0;
        for (var cmd in commands) {
            if (commands[cmd].group.toUpperCase() === 'USER') {
                commandsFound++;
                embed.addFeild('${commands[cmd].name}', 'Description: ${commands[cmd].desc}\nUsage: ${prefix + commands[cmd].usage}');
            }
            embed.setFooter('Our Commands.');
            embed.setDescription('Command found');
        }
        message.author.send({embed});
        message.channel.send({embed: {
            color: 0x1D82B6,
            description: 'Check your DMs buddy boy ${message.author}'
        }});
        }
    }
    //Purge system
    if (msg.startsWith(prefix + 'PURGE')) {
        async function purge() {
            message.delete();
            if (!message.member.roles.find("name", "Guild Officer")) {
                message.channel.send('You need a higher rank for this command.');
                return;
            }
            if (isNaN(args[0])) {
                message.channel.send('Make sure to use a number');
                return;
            }
            const fetche = await message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: args[0]});
            console.log(fetched.size + ', Found the little cunt(s)');
            message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched)
                .catch(error => message.channel.send('Error: With the purge command, \nPlease report this to MeanTeacher.'));
    }
    purge ();
    }
});


//Token
bot.login(TOKEN);
```

and in another file I also have stored the basics of my commands

```
{
    "Help": {
        "name": "Help",
        "group": "User",
        "desc": "Displays commands.",
        "usage": "help",
    },
    "Purge": {
        "name": "Purge",
        "group": "Guild Officer",
        "desc": "Clears Messages",
        "usage": "purge <number>",
    }
}
```

Now I know it's quite basic for a lot of you but I'm still stuck down here 
I am sorry if this is simple and you don't want to help but if you could I would apprecite it a lot, thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have a miss-typed .json file, is that the whole commands.json file?

Comment: Every time you get an image file? .... Do not post text output as images; copy the text and paste it in your question!

Comment: @NubCoder - can you please respond to these comments or to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is due to the fact that you have 2 extra commas `","` in your JSON file. The last property of each command object (`"Help"` and `"Purge"`) needs to not have a comma `","` at the end.

So inside your `"Help"` command object, remove the comma at the end of the line `"usage": "help",` so that command object will now look like:

```
"Help": {
    "name": "Help",
    "group": "User",
    "desc": "Displays commands.",
    "usage": "help"
}
```

And inside your `"Purge"` command object, remove the comma at the end of the line `"usage": "purge <number>",` so that command object will now look like:

```
"Purge": {
    "name": "Purge",
    "group": "Guild Officer",
    "desc": "Clears Messages",
    "usage": "purge <number>"
}
```

So your final `json` file should look like this:

```
{
    "Help": {
        "name": "Help",
        "group": "User",
        "desc": "Displays commands.",
        "usage": "help"
    },
    "Purge": {
        "name": "Purge",
        "group": "Guild Officer",
        "desc": "Clears Messages",
        "usage": "purge <number>"
    }
}
```